Firefox won't build unless it is a mercurial repository
It's impossible to build Firefox without it being a mercurial repo, which is a pain for me wanting to use GIT. Tried using the GitHub mirror but somehow there are yet more errors about mercurial.
I tried everything including moving the .hg folder from the latest version of Firefox.
All I really want is a way to get rid of depending on mercurial, as it's impossible to do anything I need to do with the code.
Errors:
5:57.28 Error running mach:
 5:57.29     mach --log-no-times artifact install
 5:57.29 This is a user error and does not appear to be a bug in mach.
 5:57.30 If filing a bug, please include the full output of mach, including this error
 5:57.30 message.
 5:57.30 The details of the failure are as follows:
 5:57.31 mach.util.UserError: Could not list any recent revisions in your clone. Does your clone have git-cinnabar metadata? If not, consider re-cloning using the directions at https://github.com/glandium/git-cinnabar/wiki/Mozilla:-A-git-workflow-for-Gecko-development

mozconfig:
ac_add_options --enable-artifact-builds

Edit: Building on Linux (if that matters)
I'm also new to the whole mercurial thing and Firefox source btw
